# finding rational roots

Tags: quadratics

Consider the integral expression in $x$ 
$$P=x^3+x^2+ax+1,$$
where $a$ is a rational number. At $a= ?$ the value of $P$ is a rational number for any $x$ which satisfies the equation $x^2+2x−2=0$, and in this case the value of $P=?$

I don't know how the answer came key  $P= -1$, $A=-4$.

What I did is I tried to find the second equation roots but it is irrational. I don't know how to get the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $x^2 + 2x − 2 = 0,\;$ then
$\quad x^2 = 2 - 2x \;$ and
$\quad x^3 = 2x - 2x^2 = 2x - 2(2 - 2x) = 6x - 4$

So $P = x^3 + x^2 + ax + 1 = (6x-4) + (2-2x) + ax + 1 = (4+a)x - 1$

You should be able to see the rest.

Comment: i'm sorry I did't get how 2x-2x^2=2x-2(2-2x)

Comment: @ShaymaFaiz: Look at the previous line: $x^2 = 2 - 2x$.

Answer (score 0):

We want $(x^2+2x-2)(x+b)=x^3+x^2+ax+1-P$. Expanding the lefthand side we get $x^3+(b+2)x^2+(2b-2)x-2b$. To get the correct coefficient of $x^2$ we need $b=-1$. The lefthand side then becomes $x^3+x^2-4x+2$. So we need $a=-4,P=-1$.

Alternatively, the sum of the two roots of $x^2+2x-2$ is $-2$ (minus the coefficient of $x^2$). Similarly, the sum of the three roots to $x^3+x^2+ax+1-P=0$ is $-1$. So the third root must be $1$. Hence we must have: $(x^2+2x-2)(x-1)=x^3+x^2+ax+1-P$. Hence $a=-4,P=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

From the quadratic formula, the solutions of $x^2-2x-2=0$ are $x=-1\pm\sqrt{3}$

Substituting $x=-1\pm\sqrt{3}$  into $P=x^3+x^2+ax+1$ gives: $\left( \pm\sqrt{3}-1\right) \,a\pm4\,\sqrt{3}-5$. As $a$ is rational, for this to be rational requires that the $\sqrt{3}$ terms cancel, and this occurs when $a=-4$ and then $P=-1$

Comment: so I'm allowed to cancel that because the question asked it has to be rational

Comment: @ShaymaFaiz for $b\ne0$ rational  $b\sqrt{3}$ is irrational, so for $b\sqrt{3}$ to be rational requires $b=0$, so the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: why not take -5 as A? I still don't really get it

Comment: @ShaymaFaiz because if $a=-5$ you get $P_{(x=-1\pm\sqrt{3})}=\mp\sqrt{3}$ which is irrational.